# Swift bad conversion

Tags: string, swift, casting, int

I try do something that :

```
 var Size = textfield.text
    Size = Int(Size) * 7
```

Could someone tell my why its not working ? Swift 2.2 changed someting in casting ?

Comment: That did not compile in *any* Swift version. Your `Size` variable has type `String` (or `String?`), you cannot assign an integer to it.

Comment: I found similar examples :/ Could you write correct casting ?

Comment: What examples? – First of all, you should read the exact error message (and add that to  your question). Perhaps that gives a clue already?

Comment: OP, do yourself a favor and read the [Swift Basics online documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309) by Apple. It's very well written and covers, well, all the basics, and then more. :)

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
if var Size = Int(textfield.text) {
    Size *= 7
    print(Size)
}
```

Note that the body of the if statement is only executed if, the text in the 
textfield can be converted to an `Int`. This is called Optional Binding (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH21-ID245).